# Line continuation/wrapping in doctest

Tags: python, doctest

I am using `doctest.testmod()` to do some basic testing. I have a function that returns a long string, say `get_string()`. Something like:

```
def get_string(a, b):
    r''' (a, b) -> c

    >>> get_string(1, 2)
    'This is \n\n a long \n string with new \
    space characters \n\n'
    # Doctest should work but does not.

    '''
    return ('This is \n\n a long \n string ' + \
            'with new space characters \n\n')
```

The problem is that the doctest is not passing because it is expecting a single line string, and it is treating the wrap as a `\n` character. Is there a way to get around this?

PS: This is not the actual function I am working with, but a minimal version for your sake.

Comment: Note: in your code in the `return` line the backslash is **useless** if not harmful. Parenthesis are enough for continuing lines (and they should be preferred anyway). Besides, even the `+` is superfluous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you understood how `doctest` works. It does **not** check whether the output is somehow "equivalent", it only checks if the output is **identical** (with only very minor possible variations, like using ellipsis). From the documentation:

> The `doctest` module searches for pieces of text that look like
>   interactive Python sessions, and then executes those sessions **to
>   verify that they work *exactly* as shown.**

Doctest matches the *output* (**not** a string literal, a python expression or whatever. Raw output bytes) with the content of the sample output you provide. Since it doesn't know that the text between quotes represents a string literal it cannot interpret it as you want.

In other words: the only thing you can do is to simply put the whole output on one line as in:

```
>>> get_string(1, 2)
    'This is \n\n a long \n string with new space characters \n\n'
```

If the output of this is too long you can try to modify the example to produce a shorter string (e.g. cutting it to `50` characters: `get_string(1, 2)[:50]`). If you look at doctests of different projects you'll find different hacks to make doctests more readable while providing reliable output.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE` option (see also [full list of options](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html#option-flags)).

Here is an example from [doctest documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html#directives):

```
>>> print range(20) # doctest: +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE
[0,   1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,
10,  11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are making a test against a long single-line string in the output,
you can keep the doctest match string within 80 characters for PEP8 goodness
by using doctest's ELLIPSIS feature, where `...` will match any string.
While it is generally used for variable output like object addresses,
it works just fine with (long) fixed output as well, for example:

```
def get_string(a, b):
    r''' (a, b) -> c

    >>> get_string(1, 2)  # doctest: +ELLIPSIS
    'This is ... string with newline characters \n\n'
    '''
    return ('This is \n\n a long \n string '
            'with newline characters \n\n')
```

There is a small loss of exactness in the matching, but this is usually not critical for tests.

Answer (score 1):

From doctest's docs:

If you continue a line via backslashing in an interactive session, or for any other reason use a backslash, you should use a raw docstring, which will preserve your backslashes exactly as you type them:

```
>>> def f(x):
...     r'''Backslashes in a raw docstring: m\n'''
>>> print f.__doc__
Backslashes in a raw docstring: m\n
```

Otherwise you could use a double-backslash.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is `>>> repr(get_string(1,2))`; that will escape new lines and use a single-line string just for the test.

I'd prefer a solution where you can say:

```
>>> get_string(1,2)
first line
second line

fourth
```

In your case, this is a problem because you have trailing white space.

Also note that it's not possible to test the line continuation character.

```
"a" + \
"b"
```

is exactly the same as

```
"a" + "b"
```

namely `"ab"`

Comment: Sounds like the best solution so far, although I *would* like to test for newline characters too, since in this case things could go wrong in my program if they are badly placed. Thanks though!

Comment: `repr()` allows exactly that, so I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Actually, I haven't been able to implement the doctest with `repr(...)`. It does escape the new lines, but the line continuation is still interpreted as a newline character, and thus the test doesn't pass. Could you show me an example of how it would look like?

Comment: Ah. There is no way to test a line continuation character since backslash followed by a newline will be simply swallowed. It doesn't appear in the result at all. The parser removes it before the `string` class has a chance to see it. So `"a" + \ "b"` is exactly the same as `"a" + "b"` or `"ab"` after calling the method. There is no way to write a test for this unless you ask the Python interpreter for the source code of the method and find the respective lines.

Comment: Oh, the line continuation that I'm having trouble with is the one in the docstring. I *am* effectively making a test against a single-line string (the line continuation in the actual function doesn't matter). However, the problem is that the string in the doctest is interpreted as having several lines.

Comment: Well, you can't use line continuation in docstring. I'm pretty sure that the **output** of the Python methods isn't parsed by Python, so there is no one who could remove the LC. You will have to paste a very, very long single line string into the doctest.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, which your documentation readers may prefer, is to use pprint to pretty up the output instead of doing it by hand.

```
POEM = """ My mother groaned, my father wept:
Into the dangerous world I leapt,
Helpless, naked, piping loud,
Like a fiend hid in a cloud.

Struggling in my father’s hands,
Striving against my swaddling bands,
Bound and weary, I thought best
To sulk upon my mother’s breast."""

def poem():
    """
    Enumerate the lines of INFANT SORROW

    >>> import pprint
    >>> pprint.pprint(poem())
    {0: ' My mother groaned, my father wept:',
     1: 'Into the dangerous world I leapt,',
     2: 'Helpless, naked, piping loud,',
     3: 'Like a fiend hid in a cloud.',
     4: '',
     5: 'Struggling in my father’s hands,',
     6: 'Striving against my swaddling bands,',
     7: 'Bound and weary, I thought best',
     8: 'To sulk upon my mother’s breast.'}
    """
    lines = POEM.split("\n")
    return {lineno:line for lineno, line in enumerate(lines)}
```